# Firing custom event in the UI thread

Tags: c#, delegates, thread-safety

The example below functions fine, but I want to have the `Complete` event fire its event handlers in the UI thread.  I don't want `HasCompleted()` to have to worry about checking if it's on the UI thread or not.  Calls to `HasCompleted()` should always be invoked on the UI thread. How do I do this?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var game = new Game();
        game.Complete += HasCompleted;
        game.Load();
    }

    private void HasCompleted()
    {
        if (label1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            label1.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => label1.Text = "complete"));
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Text = "complete";
        }
    }
}

public class Game
{
    public Game()
    {

    }

    public event MethodInvoker Complete;

    public void Load()
    {
        var task = new Task(new Action(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(500);
                OnComplete();
            }));
        task.Start();
    }

    private void OnComplete()
    {
        if (Complete != null)
        {
            Complete();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why have you got a public Complete field? Surely you want to use an event instead... anyway, at that point, do you basically mean that `OnComplete` should execute *all* the Complete event handlers on the UI thread? Is the `Game` instance *always* created in the UI thread? (If so, it can get the synchronization context at the right time...)

Comment: Yes sorry, Complete is an Event, i will amend. Yes OnComplete should execute all event handlers on UI thread. Game is created on UI thread. I don't understand synchronization context, I will read on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Capture the current synchronization context when you create the `Game` object and use that to marshal the event to the context that was current when the object was first created:

```
public class Game
{
    private SynchronizationContext context;
    public Game()
    {
        context = SynchronizationContext.Current ??
            new SynchronizationContext();
    }

    public MethodInvoker Complete;

    public void Load()
    {
        //...
    }

    private void OnComplete()
    {
        if (Complete != null)
        {
            context.Post(_ => Complete(), null);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Servy, Jon. This has done the trick. Do you think i should rename the thread title to something more appropriate? This is my first thread :)

Comment: @DeanLafferty I've edited your title to something more appropriate on your behalf.

Comment: This solves [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48308418/c-sharp-invoke-event-outside-thread-to-avoid-illegalcrossthreadcall?noredirect=1#comment83602274_48308418)